# Search for names in name manager and set values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a lot of named ranges. They all are like `MFiles_PG9317B4DE414D4DE3A781648B8F8B5C2Fn1_ID`. Common thing to all of them is that they all start with `MFiles_`. Time to times I need to set their values to `""`. Clicking each one and setting value manually is one of a job. I would like to do it by code. I guess I have to loop through all of them, search for names starting with `MFiles_` and set their value to `""`. How to do that?

Note! Named ranges should stay as they are, only values should be set to `""`. So `MFiles_PG9317B4DE414D4DE3A781648B8F8B5C2Fn1_ID` with value (for example) `=78324` after code run should be `""` but name should stay untouched `MFiles_PG9317B4DE414D4DE3A781648B8F8B5C2Fn1_ID`. Also all the others begging with `MFiles_`

```
Sub NamedRange_Loop()

Dim nm As Name

'Loop through each named range in workbook
  For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
    If nm = MFiles_ Then
       Name.Value =""
    End If
  Next nm

End Sub
```

---

**EDIT:**

Mikku's solution gives:
[image]

Comment: Use `Range(nm).Value = ""` , that ways your Named Range won't go anywhere. Use the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57176447/5720144)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close :)

```
Sub NamedRange_Loop()

Dim nm As Name

'Loop through each named range in workbook
  For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
    If InStr(1, nm.Name, "MFiles_") Then
       nm.RefersTo = "=""""" 'nm.Value = "=""""" does the same thing
    End If
  Next nm

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think they should delete the Named Range. Do you know any reason why that should be the case ?

Comment: I tried to set the values of Named Ranges to `""` , but the Named Ranges are intact after that. They are not deleted from Name Manager

Comment: See in my Answer, name stays the same. i ran the code 3 times.

Comment: I think it is because the way we are setting it's value.

Comment: `nm.Value = 0` this works but then I have all flooded with (0) zeros in my Excel application

Comment: Thank you! You saved couple of days a year in my life by this code.

Comment: @user7202022, I'll write a cheque to your boss ;). Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

**Something Like this:**

```
Sub NamedRange_Loop()

Dim nm As Name

  For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names

       If Left(nm.Name, 7) = "MFiles_" Then

         Range(nm).Value = ""

       End If

  Next nm

End Sub
```

---

**If you will use `nm.Value = ""` it will delete the Named Ranges. But if you use `Range(nm).Value = ""` it will retain the Named Ranges as it is.**

[image]